# Como manipular objetos dentro de uma div?

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Sou iniciante em programação web e já fiz de tudo o que sabia. Alguém pode me ajudar a centralizar esses itens um ao lado do outro de preferência com espaçamento menor???

OBS.: Eu consegui espaçar demais ou não espaçar como podem ver nas imagens. Meu objetivo era deixar um ao lado do outro.

[image: imagem de lojas na horizontal]

[image: imagem de lojas na vertical]

Trecho do código:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Disponibilize seu código como texto e não como imagem, senão fica difícil reproduzir o problema e te ajudar.

Comment: Estou tentando achar aqui, como é minha primeira pergunta aqui...tudo é novo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Olá @Jeferson-Heavy, vamos ver se conseguimos clarear essa idéia... então vc precisa de 3 colunas com uma imagem e título dentro de cada. Vou ver se consigo lhe passar a melhor solução dentro de sua arquitetura. Vou colocar aqui o trecho que vc deverá corrigir em seu código, já aproveito e deixo o exemplo para vc ver o formato ideal de postar o código aqui nas postagens:

```
<style>
.box_wrapp{
    display:inline-block;
    width:100%;
    text-align:center;
}
.box{
    display:inline-block;
    width:150px;
    max-width:90%;
    margin:0 10px 10px 0;
}
.box .b_header{
    display:inline-block;
    width:100%;
    text-align:center;
    padding:10px 0 10px 0;
    font-size:12px;
}
.box .b_body{
    display:inline-block;
    width:100%;
    height:100px;
    border-radius:50%;
    overflow:hidden;    
    font-size:12px;
}
#box1 .b_body{
    background:url(pasta/img1.png)no-repeat center;
    background-size:cover;
    background-color:#e8e8e8; 
}
#box2 .b_body{
    background:url(pasta/img2.png)no-repeat center;
    background-size:cover;
    background-color:#e8e8e8;
}
#box3 .b_body{
    background:url(pasta/img3.png)no-repeat center;
    background-size:cover;
    background-color:#e8e8e8;
}
</style>

<div class="box_wrapp">

    <div class="box" id="box1">

        <div class="b_header">
        Título
        </div><!-- /b_header-->

        <div class="b_body"></div><!-- /b_body-->       

    </div><!-- /box1-->

    <!-- ... -->    

    <div class="box" id="box2">

        <div class="b_header">
        Título
        </div><!-- /b_header-->

        <div class="b_body"></div><!-- /b_body-->       

    </div><!-- /box2-->

    <!-- ... -->

    <div class="box" id="box3">

        <div class="b_header">
        Título
        </div><!-- /b_header-->

        <div class="b_body"></div><!-- /b_body-->

    </div><!-- /box3-->

</div><!-- /box_wrapp-->
```

https://jsfiddle.net/nmq6tecw/2/

Comment: Muito Obrigado amigo!

Comment: Oi @Jeferson-Heavy, conseguiu resolver? fico feliz em ter ajudado... Pode marcar a resposta como resolvido caso tenha concluído.

Answer (score 0):

Amigo, uma boa seria criar 3 divs e deixá-las dessa maneira no CSS:

```
div#cidade1 {
  min-width: 33%;
  max-width: 100%;
  position: relative;
}
```

Aplica isso nas 3 divs. Espero ter ajudado :)
Dessa maneira, ele já se adapta aos smartphones.

Comment: Obrigado pelas dicas, já resolvi sim. Por mais insignificante que tenha sido essa minha dúvida, estou muito entusiasmado e motivado à estudar mais sobre programação web!

Comment: Que bom cara! Também estou começando nessa área e um pouco (muito) indeciso.